# Apache 2.4 and PHP-FPM sockets

Tags: apache, sockets, php, mod-proxy

Couldn't find anywhere the answer to question that bothers me for a few days:

According to [Apache documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) in virtual host files I should write this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/path/to/socket.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/your/documentroot/
```

But Do I have to use another fcgi port for other sites? e.g.

```
...socket2.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001...
...socket3.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002...
```

Or

```
...socket2.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000...
...socket3.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000...
```

It works both ways – no errors in logs or on screen. I know that if I would use TCP not UNIX sockets I should use different port for each site (and also it would throw an error if I use the same port) but I'm not sure I understand this Apache syntax.

Comment: You are not correct about TCP. For TCP too you can use the same port for different virtualhost. The port will just translate to the worker pool and have not much to do with the site themselves. You should decide if you want to use the same pools for all your virtualhosts or not. There is no technical limitations there

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you configure your workers pools for php-fpm.

On centos 7 for example, you will find a www.conf in /etc/php-fpm.d/

This is generally the configuration for port 9000.

You can use the same port for all your virtualhost without any issue.

But if by design you want to use a different port for different virtualhosts, you can just duplicate the www.conf, rename it and edit the file.

Make sure you change the name of the pool at the top. You will find the default name to be [www]. You can edit it to [your_preferred_pool_name]

Then in the listen option you can change the port to what you want.

After restarting php-fpm you will have your [www] pool and your [your_preferred_pool_name] pool.

To configure a virtualhost to use the new pool, just update the ProxyPassMatch configuration by updating the port to  your newly defined port in the conf file.

But again, using the same pool (port) for all your virtualhosts should work without any issue.

Comment: The OP is asking how to configure using sockets probably to avoid the overhead with TCP.